# How to achieve `select * from InternalProductionDb order by DateTimeStamp desc limit 10` in aws-dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb, the table structure is as follows：
[image: InternalProductionDb]
the PK `StatusId` is `String`,and the sort key `DateTimeStamp` is `Number`.
I wanna achieve `select * from InternalProductionDb order by DateTimeStamp desc limit 10;`

```
let params = {
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':min': {
            N: '200000000000'
        },
        ':max': {
            N: '300000000000'
        },
        ':beg':{
            S:'2'
        }
    },
    TableName: "InternalProductionDb",
    ConsistentRead: true,
    Limit: 10,
    KeyConditionExpression:' DateTimeStamp between :min and :max and begins_with(StatusId,:beg)' ,
    ScanIndexForward:true
};
let res = await ddb.query(params).promise();
console.dir(res);
return res;
```

In fact, because I don't need to make any conditional judgments, I don't really need `KeyConditionExpression`, but the API must specify the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter.So I wrote two inevitable judgment statements.
I think this is too complicated and I got an error.
the error is `Query key condition not supported`，
So is anyone aware of the right solution?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB is not a relational database!  What you're asking for is a pretty complicated query against your schema.

You need a schema optimized for time series queries, such as "get 10 most recent items in the table". Such a schema would have to offer a compromise between horizontal scaling (which is what Dynamo offers out of the box) and locality of data in order to assemble your response.

One option would be to partition your data by date. For example use the date as a Partition Key and the timestamp as the sort key. Then, assuming you get enough data, in order to answer your query you'd only need to look at today and potentially the day before.

Things of course get trickier if you don't always get enough data each day, in which case figuring out what is the most recent date is more complicated. You could change the granularity of the partition key to be by week/month.

You could also employ some other sort of schema where you keep "recent" data all in one partition and rotate old data out.

But here's another thought: you could create two tables - one that stores every item and one where you keep only the most recent. You can use TTL on the "most recent table" and drop records older than a certain threshold and on this table you can set the schema up such that all items fall in the same partition (ie. they have the same value for PK) and then use the timestamp as a sort key. Then getting most recent top 10 becomes an easy query.

Or, you could use a relational database in conjunction with your DynamoDB for analytical queries..

Further reading: [Best Practices for Time Series Databases on DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html)

Comment: Link to DynamoDB docs about [best practices for time-series data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html)

Comment: Thanks @Charles - I've added the reference